# popen Not Working On Windows 7 Apache Server While Works Fine On Windows Xp Apache Server

Tags: php, xampp, popen, easyphp

i was trying to run a executable in background.

I am ussing following code and it's working fine on my windows xp apache server (Easyphp). but while i am trying that on my windows 7 apache server (XAMPP) it not working.

On XP it opens the notepad but on windows 7 it does not open at all, i checked task manager it's not there also.

Here is the code that i tried:

```
<?php
execInBackground('""c:\Windows\notepad.exe""');
echo 'i am done!';
function execInBackground($cmd)
{
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows")
    {
        pclose(popen('start /B "" '. $cmd, 'r')); 
    }
    else
    {
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");  
    }
} 
?>
```

**Note:** XAMPP on windows 7 running as a windows service, while on XP easyphp is not running as a service. Is that is the cause?

best regards

Comment: Did you found any solution? I have same problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a folder within the logged in user's scope (ie.  c:\users\bobby\desktop)?  I have found that on Windows 7 and 10 the default permissions will not allow to write to files on the C: or C:\windows directly.

If you can do it within the users own scope, you can narrow it down to a permissions issue.

Comment: sir, yes i have tried to use something from desktop, but that even didn't work. And also i don't think that a write issue as i only read/open/execute notepad. Nothing writing on windows directory.

Comment: Just for giggles, look under C:\users\<username>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\ and look for a subfolder for Windows.  On my Windows 10 machine anything I try to create or save ends up going there as a shadow copy.  I know this isn't a solution, but it may help point the right way